# On computing a conditional expectation for countable-co-countable sigma-algebras

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Let $S=[0,1]$  equipped with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra ${\cal B}. $ 
Assign on it a purely atomic probability measure, $P $.
Let ${\cal A} $ be the sub-$\sigma$-algebra generated by the countable and co-countable sets.
Now, take $B=[0, 1/2]. $
What is $E_{P}[I_B \mid {\cal A}] $ ? 
Since there is a countable set $A =\{x\in S: P({x}) > 0\} $ and ${\cal A} $ contains all singletons, I am tempted to say that   $E_{P}(I_B \mid {\cal A})(x) =I_B(x) $ for all $x \in A. $ However, I do not seem to be able to make this argument rigorous.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think $I_{B \cap supp(P)}$.  As $supp(P) $ is countable that is in the sigma-algebra, and for any $A \in \mathcal A,\mathbb E(I_B I_A) = \mathbb E(I_B I_A I_{supp(P)}) = \mathbb E(I_{B\cap supp(P)} I_A)$

Comment: $I_B(x) = 1 $ if $x\in B, $ the characteristic or indicator function. I think that A is the support of $P $ since it consists of those $x\in S $ for which $P(\{x\}) > 0. $

Comment: o.k I guess $I_B = I_{B \cap supp(A)}$ a.e. anyway

Comment: Yes, thank you. That was my conclusion. But how do you justify it rigorously? Using the definition of conditional expectation: $\int_A 1_B(x) P(dx) = \int_A E[1_B\mid {\cal A}] P(dx) $ I mean?

Comment: Mike gave the justification: $\mathbf 1_{B\cap A}$ is $\mathcal A$-measurable because $B\cap A$ is countable, and $\int_C \mathbf 1_B P(dx)=\int_C \mathbf 1_{B\cap A} P(dx)$ for any Borel set $C$. Or am I missing something?